# How to ensure sequential module wise test case execution in multi module gradle project?

Tags: java, gradle, junit, build.gradle

I have a multi-module gradle project where each module has some test cases. With the default gradle behavior, test cases within a module run sequentially but test tasks of multiple modules will run in parallel. Due to some internal reason, I want to avoid this behavior and achieve the following things.

- Each module's test task should run once the previous module's test execution is done.
- Test cases present with a module should execute sequentially. ( happening by default )

Below is the build.gradle of my root project. Please suggest what changes can be done for the same.

```
/****************************************
 * instructions for all projects
 ****************************************/

allprojects {
    apply from: "$rootDir/dependencies.gradle"
    apply from: "$rootDir/build.properties"

    apply plugin: 'project-report'
    apply plugin: 'java-library'
    apply plugin: 'maven-publish'


    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        mavenLocal()
    }

    group = projectName
    projectVersion = projectVersion + '.' + jenkinsBuildNumber
    version = projectVersion

    sourceCompatibility = 11
    targetCompatibility = 11

}

/****************************************
 * instructions for each sub project
 ****************************************/
subprojects {
    apply plugin: 'jacoco'
    jacoco {
        toolVersion = "0.8.5"
        reportsDir = file("$buildDir/reports/jacoco")
    }

    jacocoTestReport {
        def coverageSourceDirs = ['src/main/java/']
        reports {
            xml.enabled false
            csv.enabled false
            html.enabled true
        }
    }

    // common dependencies
    dependencies {
        testImplementation(
                libs.testng,
        )
    }

    test {
        systemProperty "file.encoding", "utf-8"
        useTestNG()
        testLogging.showStandardStreams = true
        testLogging.exceptionFormat = 'full'
        testLogging {
            events "passed", "skipped", "failed"
        }
        finalizedBy jacocoTestReport

    }
}
```